# Visual Indication of Focus and Adding Click Event To all TextBoxes

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on a program wherein I have around 400 Text Boxes and I need to program an effect to make them show that they have focus. I can get the visual part down (Unless someone knows how to add a soft blue outline to a text box in VB), but I'm having trouble with creating GotFocus and LostFocus events that handle all of my Text Boxes at once. I've tried

```
Dim txtBox = Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)
Private Sub TextBox_GotFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtBox.GotFocus
```

But I get a "Must have WithEvents variable" error which I don't quite understand how to fix. I've tried

```
Public Sub txtBoxGotFocusHandler(ByVal sender As Object,
ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        For Each txtBox As TextBox In Me.Controls 'References all text boxes in form
            If txtBox.Focus = True Then
                txtBox.BackColor = Color.Black
            End If
        Next
```

And I've tried a few other somewhat related things I've seen around the internet, but to no avail. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `I have around 400 Text Boxes` your users must love you.  There is no need to loop thru controls in that event.  The sender argument tells you which one

Comment: @Plutonix Maybe it is 20×20 tic tac toe :)

Comment: 400 TextBoxes = Use a Grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your app at runtime with any controls. You could query the layout of your app from SQL and from a simple change your app layout changes.

```
Private FocusRectangle As System.Drawing.Graphics
Private OldRectangle As System.Drawing.Graphics
Private MyTextBoxes As New List(Of TextBox)
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    MyTextBoxes.Clear()
    For xcount = 0 To 399
        MyTextBoxes.Add(New TextBox)
        With MyTextBoxes.Item(xcount)
            .Name = "MyTextBoxes" & (xcount + 1).ToString
            .Text = ""
            .Location = New Point(0, 0)
            .Size = New Size(50, 13)
            .Visible = True
            AddHandler .GotFocus, AddressOf MyTextBoxes_GotFocus
            AddHandler .LostFocus, AddressOf MyTextBoxes_LostFocus


        End With
        Me.Controls.Add(MyTextBoxes.Item(xcount))
        'add them to a panel....
        'Panel1.Controls.add(MyTextBoxes.Item(xcount))
    Next
End Sub
Sub MyTextBoxes_GotFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim ThisTextBox As TextBox = DirectCast(sender, TextBox)
    Dim xPen As New System.Drawing.Pen(Color.LightBlue)
    FocusRectangle = Me.CreateGraphics()
    FocusRectangle.DrawRectangle(xPen, ThisTextBox.Location.X - 1, ThisTextBox.Location.Y - 1, ThisTextBox.Size.Width + 1, ThisTextBox.Size.Height + 1)
    OldRectangle = FocusRectangle
End Sub
Sub MyTextBoxes_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim ThisTextBox As TextBox = DirectCast(sender, TextBox)
    OldRectangle.Dispose()
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseMove
    MyTextBoxes.Item(0).Focus()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you created your form with the Designer, the WithEvents is added for you automatically.

If you are declaring 400 text boxes as Private fields, you would declare them as `Private WitheEvents txtBox As TextBox`

If you're creating the text boxes programatically and adding them to a collection of textboxes or something, then you can't do WithEvents.

But all WithEvents does is allow you to add `Handeles TextBox.SomeEvent` to a function.  Instead you can do this:

```
   Dim txtBox As New TextBox
   ...
   AddHandler txtBox.GotFocus, AddressOf txtBoxGotFocusHandler
   Me.Controls.Add(txtBox)
```